# Is there a way to kill windows process from protractor spec?

Tags: windows, selenium, jasmine, protractor

Since Firefox has ugly timing bug with it's Plugin container I need a way to kill it before closing the browser. I need something like

> Runtime().getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im WefFault.exe")

but to be executed from jasmine/protractor spec. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741061/java-script-kill-windows-process?noredirect=1#comment57228031_34741061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protractor is built on top of WebDriverJS, which uses native events and browser-specific drivers to interact with your application as a user would.

Since protractor is restricted to WebDriverJS, if you want to kill a windows process you'll have to use an external script. This link can show you how do it in the command line https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb491009.aspx